# is it ok to not define class defaults?

Tags: python

sparing the details of context and why i care...

is it okay to do this:

```
class IsThisOk(object):
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        for k in kwargs:
            setattr( self, k, kwargs[k] )
obj = IsThisOk( apples=2 , oranges=2 )
```

because I've always approached it as:

```
class OptionB(object):
    apples = None
    oranges = None
    """class defaults"""
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        for k in kwargs:
            setattr(self,k,kwargs[k])
b = OptionB( apples=2 , oranges=2 )
```

=====

edit :

i originally had this in the above , which is something I shouldn't have...

```
class OptionA(object):
    """set self.k but with class defaults"""
    apples = None
    oranges = None
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        for k in kwargs:
            self.k = kwargs[k]
a = OptionA( apples=2 , oranges=2 )
```

This all came from me trying to optimize some code.

i also noted that::

```
    for k in kwargs:
        setattr( self, k, kwargs[k] )
```

is a bit faster than

```
    for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
        setattr( self, k, v )
```

Comment: You do realize that `self.k = ...` just creates an attribute `k`, not an attribute with the name of whatever the variable `k` contains? (This is in contest to the version using `setattr`.)

Comment: and that is why i've always used setattr...  i was hastily trying to optimize some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As delnan commented, neither `IsThisOk` or `OptionA` will work as you've shown. That's because `self.k = kwargs[k]` is equivalent to `setattr(self, "k", kwargs[k])` rather than the desired call you use in `OptionB`.

An alternative solution might be to use the `namedtuple` class factory from the `collections` module in the standard library:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> OptionC = namedtuple("OptionC", ["apples", "oranges"])
>>> c = OptionC(2, 2) # you can also use keyword arguments, if you wish
>>> print(c)
OptionC(apples=2, oranges=2)
```

The limitation of this option is that OptionC instances will be immutable, like it's parent class `tuple`. That is, you won't be able to do `c.apples = 5` after the instance has been created.

To answer the question in the title though, no, it is not necessary to define default variables in a class definition. In fact, I think it is discouraged. If you want there to be optional arguments to your class constructor, give them defaults in the `__init__` method's definition:

```
class OptionD:
    def __init__(apples=None, oranges=None):
        self.apples = apples
        self.oranges = oranges
```

Comment: thanks.  the real concern i had was answered by "no, it is not necessary to define default variables in a class definition."

i just quickly tossed that code together to do a bench of class defaults vs not, and for some reason started comparing `self.k`

Answer (score -3):

*Edit* As stated in the comments, this is pretty much an example of what not to do.

```
...
for k in kwargs:
  exec('self.{}={}'.format(k,kwargs[k]))
...
```

Comment: Nooooo. What if someone passes in the value `"destroy_the_server()"`? `setattr` does this *so* much cleaner and safer.

Comment: Plus, *it doesn't even work* (for really simple and innocent values, like strings or most user-defined objects).

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  I use python for personal use and haven't delved into the security issues much.  I do love some exec() action though :)